# Java Format String Error with Maven Build

Tags: java, maven

When I kick off my maven build, it fails with this error

> "Conversion = s, Flags = #"

on the below test.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String a = String.format("%1$#" + (250 + 1) + "s", "");
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is really all down to a call which looks like this:

```
String.format("%1$#251s", "");
```

If you look at the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) docs, this format string is requesting a string conversion (`s`) with a width of 251 and a flag of `#`.

The docs for string conversions state:

> If the '#' flag is given and the argument is not a Formattable , then a FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException will be thrown.

Now `java.lang.String` doesn't implement `Formattable` - so the exception is thrown, exactly as documented.

What did you *expect* this to do?

Comment: I had no idea what it did. I had made changes to code in O&M, and then saw that this particular test failed. I didn't understand what it was supposed to do. Thanks, Jon.

Comment: Previously this unit test succeeded. However, I just upgraded to Java 1.7. Is the constraint that you listed new to 1.7?

Comment: @Kevin: Not that I'm aware of, although it's possible that it didn't validate as thoroughly previously.

Comment: Thank you kindly <filling up space>